How to access data from a Synology NAS after it died (4 disk RAID, btrfs)
I've had a Synology DS918+ running for some years and finally the mainboard died. I've read multiple articles, questions and posts about similar situations but haven't found any help yet.
Sadly I have very little experience with RAIDs, so I'm not totally sure what the NAS did when creating the RAID, but I'll try to explain it:
I had 4 disks in there, 4x4 TB. All 4 disks had btrfs and the NAS automatically created a RAID with all 4 disks (allegedly 1 disk could've failed and the data should've been fully recoverable). Is that a RAID 5? Also what I've read is, that Synology does not use the native btrfs-RAID solution (since it is/was quite buggy?), but mdadm(?, sadly I can't find the source anymore).
Then I've moved all the disks to my archlinux server, hooked them up over SATA 3 and when I type lsblk as root into the terminal, I can see the disks and I assume they still function.
lsblk


NAME            MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sda               8:0    0  3.6T  0 disk
├─sda1            8:1    0  2.4G  0 part
├─sda2            8:2    0    2G  0 part
└─sda5            8:5    0  3.6T  0 part
└─md127         9:127  0 10.9T  0 raid5
└─vg1000-lv 253:0    0 10.9T  0 lvm
sdb               8:16   0  3.6T  0 disk
├─sdb1            8:17   0  2.4G  0 part
├─sdb2            8:18   0    2G  0 part
└─sdb5            8:21   0  3.6T  0 part
└─md127         9:127  0 10.9T  0 raid5
└─vg1000-lv 253:0    0 10.9T  0 lvm
sdc               8:32   0  3.6T  0 disk
├─sdc1            8:33   0  2.4G  0 part
├─sdc2            8:34   0    2G  0 part
└─sdc5            8:37   0  3.6T  0 part
└─md127         9:127  0 10.9T  0 raid5
└─vg1000-lv 253:0    0 10.9T  0 lvm
sdd               8:48   0  3.6T  0 disk
├─sdd1            8:49   0  2.4G  0 part
├─sdd2            8:50   0    2G  0 part
└─sdd5            8:53   0  3.6T  0 part
└─md127         9:127  0 10.9T  0 raid5
└─vg1000-lv 253:0    0 10.9T  0 lvm
zram0           254:0    0 62.7G  0 disk  [SWAP]
nvme0n1         259:0    0  1.8T  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1     259:1    0  300M  0 part  /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p2     259:2    0  1.8T  0 part  /var/log

I'll also share the output of lvs, since that was asked in a similar post I've read.
lvs


WARNING: PV /dev/md127 in VG vg1000 is using an old PV header, modify the VG to update.
LV   VG     Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
lv   vg1000 -wi-a----- 10.90t

I am following this article, trying to recover my data. I'm at the following point:
mdadm -AsfR && vgchange -ay


mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically

I've looked into the help of mdadm, but I'm not sure what is wrong or how to proceed since I want to avoid possibly damaging/losing any data by experimenting myself. Any insight or advice would be highly appreciated!
Edit: I am slowly making progress, but this is a hell of a ride so far (ty Synology...)
I found this post. With lots of trial and error I've done:

install and set up VirtualBox on my linux server

reboot after installation or you'll be missing /sbin/vboxconfig


created an Ubuntu 18.04.6 Bionic Beaver LTS VM (download; don't use unattended installation, it'll break your terminal and you'll reinstall... (ty VirtualBox))

don't change the Domain, the 'Finish' button stopped working for me after that... (ty VirtualBox)
during installation I 'detached' the virtual network adapter, since I was not allowed to uncheck automatic updates (ty Ubuntu...)


on the host: go to the VM folder, create RawDisks for all the drives in your former RAID (/dev/sda-/dev/sdd for me):

VBoxManage createmedium disk --filename sda.vmdk --format=VMDK --variant RawDisk --property RawDrive=/dev/sda


in VirtualBox: VM -> Settings -> Storage -> hover mouse over SATA controller -> click the 'Adds hard disk' button, add all .vmdk files
in the VM:

apt-get update & apt-get install linux-image-4.15.0-108-generic


reboot and press and hold Shift, in the GRUB menu select Advanced -> select Kernel 4.15.0...
once booted up with the 4.15.0 Kernel, the instructions in the above mentioned Synology article should work, so:

apt-get install -y mdadm lvm2
mdadm -AsfR && vgchange -ay
cat /proc/mdstat
lvs


now I could mount the RAID:

mount /dev/vg1000/lv raid/ -o ro
ls -la raid/


now I have to install btrfs in the VM and try to remove synology-specific subvolumes, as mentioned on Reddit by FizzKhalif4. I will report back if the RAID will be mountable on newer Kernels after all that...


Reach out to the manufacturer telling about the model and serial number of the failed device, and how you had it set up (btrfs?) - asking how to recover the data?
